# Native Mobile App Secure Bridge to Hosted Content

Tags: .htaccess, cordova, jquery-mobile, native, .htpasswd

I would greatly appreciate some help with the following problem.

I am attempting to build an app with HTML/CSS/JQM that I plan to wrap with PhoneGap to package as a native app for deployment on Android & iOS Platforms.

The app will be basically a form for users to input information which upon submit will be posted to an email using PHP on our web server. It is of the utmost importance that the information is encrypted between the user device and our web server.

I have planned to do this by having a single terms & conditions page packaged with the native app, with the 'accept' button loading the 'form' page on the web server.

I would like to make it impossible to access the hosted 'form' page via a web browser (i.e. the only way to access the page is via the native app).

What I would like to do is to have the native app automatically log in to the web server, so that the user does not have to go through a registration process.

I have considered using Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla as a solution but as there will only ever be a single html page, jquery, jqm and php form submission scripts on the server - this seems overcomplicated.

It is very important that the hosted files are unable to be hacked as the user information being submitted is of a sensitive nature (e.g. financial information). Also the connection between the native app and the host server must be SSL.

Would a .htaccess / .htpasswd restriction be the best way to go about this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.